# get Jquery to slidedown div more than once without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So in the Last part of an AJAX long poll I'm trying to get the output data to be put in a div and slide down but it will only slide down once! It will append the div everytime but no matter what i do it will only to the animation once. I've been trying to get this to work for days now, please help.

Here is the entirety of my code.

```
//JavaID
var var_IDdatacheck  = <?php echo $javaid; ?>;
var var_IDcheck = parseInt(var_IDdatacheck);

//datacheck
var var_numdatacheck  = <?php echo $datacheck; ?>;
var var_numcheck = parseInt(var_numdatacheck);
function activitycheck() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'feedupdate.php',
        data: {function: '3test', datacheck: var_numcheck, javaid: var_IDcheck},
        success: function (check) {
            console.log(check);
            var verify = JSON.parse(check);

            if (var_IDcheck < verify['id']) {
                var_IDcheck = verify['id'];
                for (var i=0;i<var_IDcheck;i++){
                    $('#datacheck').prepend(verify[i]).slideDown('slow');
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(check) {
            console.log(check);
        }
    });
} 

$(document).ready(function()  {
    setInterval('activitycheck()',5000);
}); // document ready
```

Comment: so once it slides down, you want it to slide back up and then slide down again ?

Comment: it should be `.slideDown();`

Comment: This is part of an Ajax long poll, so eveytime my database changes there will be a new append made. So When the first change slides down, I want the change after that to slide down aswell.

Comment: If you are trying to slide down just what you prepend, this code will not work, as the object here is $('#datacheck') and not what you prepend to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another apporach would be in order:

```
<div id="parent_box">
    <div></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
   div#parent_box {
       height: 0;
       overflow: hidden;
       transition: height 1s;
   }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function slide_down(html) {
    $('div#parent_box > div').append(html);
    $('div#parent_box').css('height', $('div#parent_box > div').height());
}
</script>
```

If I'm not mistaken, calling `slide_down()` would `.append()` new data, and force the parent element to have the same height as it's child. `transtion` would animate this, and `overflow` would make sure it's not "leaking out" during animation.

You shouldn't be able to `.slideDown()` a visible element. If you append data to it, it will simply increase in size without an animation.

Comment: so i would put this function inside of the for loop?

Comment: Probably not. Half of it'd only have to be run once. Prepend first in the loop, then set it's parent to the same height and it's child.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to chain your slide animation calls. Try following code. It recursively calls animation method with new element once animation is complete for previous one.

```
if (var_IDcheck < verify['id']) {
    var_IDcheck = verify['id'];
    slideDown(0);
}

function slideDown(i){
    $('#datacheck').prepend(verify[i]).slideDown(function(){
        if(i<var_IDcheck){
            slideDown(i++)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it ends up appending the div infinite times. And it still fails to slide down after the 2nd post. I will post my entire code so you guys can have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your interval and make it a function so you can perform both tasks you wish to invoke.

```
setInterval( function() { 
  if ( $('#datacheck').is(":visible") ) { $('#datacheck').slideUp('slow'); }
  activitycheck();
}, 5000 );
```

When you invoke your interval to invoke activitycheck(), it will also check to see if #datacheck is currently visible, and if it is it will invoke a slide up transtion to hide it.

UPDATE:

I may have misunderstood your intention. If you want each new id to dropdown as it is recieved, then you will have to provide references to the ids contained within #datacheck. You can do this dynamically without changing your data by providing a wrapper for each id that can then be referenced by jquery. So your example could be changed like so...

```
if ( var_IDcheck < verify['id']) {
  var_IDcheck = verify['id'];
  for ( var i = 0; i < var_IDcheck; i++ ){
    var id_wrapper = '<div id="' + var_IDcheck + '" style="display:none;">' + var_IDcheck + '</div>';
    $('#datacheck').prepend(id_wrapper);
    $('#' + var_IDcheck).delay(300).slideDown('slow');
  }
}
```

The delay just gives a little time for the prepend to complete before sliding down.
Also, using the IDcheck value for the wrapper div id assures you will not accidentaly generate any identical div ids.